# dynamodb updateitemrequest C#

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Dynamodb documentmodel using C#. Here is following structure:

**Table:** Contacts
**Fields:**
ID
FullName
Addresses:[{Street, State, City, Zip},{Street, State, City}]

I want to add new address into addresses or can say append to list (addresses)

I am trying following code but it is not working. I am always getting Bad Request

```
 Document address = new Document();
 address["Id"] = "1";
 address["Street"] = "XYZ";
 address["state"] = "AAAA";
 address["City"] = "QQQ";
 address["Zip"] = "34556";

UpdateItemRequest updateRequest = new UpdateItemRequest
{
    TableName = "Contacts"
    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        {"Id", new AttributeValue{S = "1"}}
    },
    UpdateExpression = "SET #addresses = list_append(#addresses, :address)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"#addresses", "addresses"}
        },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            { ":address", new AttributeValue{S = address.ToString()}},

        }

};

dbClient.UpdateItem(updateRequest);
```

Can you please suggest fix for this code or any new method to do same.

Answer (score 0):

1) The `operand` should be a list

> list_append (operand, operand) – This function evaluates to a list
>   with a new element added to it. The new element must be contained in a
>   list, for example to add 2 to a list, the operand would be [2]. You
>   can append the new element to the start or the end of the list by
>   reversing the order of the operands.

2) Should use this class `DynamoDBList`

> List — use the DynamoDBList constructor.

3) **Example:-**

```
var addressList = new DynamoDBList();
addressList.Add(address);
```

4) Change the expression attribute value:-

```
ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            { ":address", new AttributeValue{L = addressList}},

        }
```

Comment: for L = addressList i get error can not implicitly convert type DynamoDBList to List<AttribueValue>